# Cannot scroll a psuedo scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I don't have any experience in web development and I am trying to build a UI Grid to display a large number of data points.

I am trying to create a scrollbar to be able to scroll all data points (let's say for arguments sake that it's 1,000,000) and should be able to scroll horizontally across all data points. It should only load a 20x20 data points and lazy load the next page when the scrollbar is moved appropriately.

I've managed to get the horizontal scrollbar to show on the screen but now I am trying to get it scroll. I am using fattable (https://github.com/fulmicoton/fattable) as my inspiration.

http://jsdo.it/jpez/Q7g0

How can I get my horizontal scrollbar to actually scroll when you click mouse on it and move it? It doesn't move at all.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element stacking order is not correct. Add `z-index: 1` to your scrollbar or move `.signal-viewport` before your scrollbars like this:

```
<div class="signal-viewport">...</div>
<div class="signal-h-scrollbar">...</div>
<div class="signal-v-scrollbar">...</div>
```

More info about the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)